When to model a multivalued attribute as a class vs a class attribute?
Is there an authoritative guidance or a commonly accepted practice as to when it  is better to model a property as an associated entity/class versus as a multi-valued attribute?
For example: a person can have multiple skills. Is there a recommended practice for deciding whether it is more suitable to model  a  Person class associated with a Skill class  or  a Person class with a multivalued Skill attribute? Or would such a decision depend on the operations that can be performed or other factors?

Hello dok, it's hard to give a recommendation. Both options are valid. Which one is best depends highly on your situation and the purpose of the model. I have voted to close this question for the following reasons: (1) It asks for an opinion (pls consider posting this in softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). (2) The last paragraph is actually a second question. Please only ask one question at a time. (3) The last paragraph is not correct English and unclear.

I think that Geert's article is worth a read: https://bellekens.com/2011/08/10/uml-best-practice-attribute-or-association/

@qwerty_so that's indeed an excellent reading, and I'm glad to see that the rule of thumb seems more broadly shared than I thought.

@Christophe Too bad that OMG has not focused on that. The dot notation came too late and it's poorly supported in tools like EA. The doppelganger nature of assoc/attrib needs ro be cleansed.

Thanks dok and @Christophe for improving the question. I have voted now to reopen it. Also, thanks Christophe for your answer. Still, I think we need a bit more context to answer the question. What kind of class diagram is needed? A domain model? A database model? A Java design? etc. It seems that dok is not sure whether Skill is a class or not. In that case, Christophe's answer will not help you. Maybe the question should be: How to decide whether a concept should be modeled as a class, a primitive type or a data type?

The distinction in UML between an attribute, a property or an associated class is very thin and subtle:

UML specifications (9.9.17): A Property is a StructuralFeature. A Property related by ownedAttribute to a Classifier (other than an association) represents an attribute and might also represent an association end. It relates an instance of the Classifier to a value or set of values of the type of the attribute.

In the end, the choice is yours. But there is an unofficial rule of thumb that can help:

if the multivalued property has a simple type, it's usually  shown as an attribute:


if a multivalued property is of the type of class, it's usually better to show it as the end of an association with that class, unless it is a relatively simple and trivial class used in many places and that doesn't deserve so much attention:


if it is a multivalued property of a type defined as «DataType», there is no generally accepted recommendation. But in principle, the attribute would  reflect more intuitively the "by value" semantic, but if it is important to show that the data type is itself associated to other classes, it could be helpful to nevertheless show it as a classifier box


